# Классификатор массивов Python

Tags: python, numpy, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

В общем вопрос.
Есть датасет в котором есть массивы и обозначения к чему они относятся вида:

```
dict = {"Запчасть 1": {
                "Модель 1": [[10, 10], [12, 12], [11, 15]], 
                "Модель 2": [[12, 11], [11, 11], [12, 13]]}, 
        "Запчасть 2": {
                "Модель 1": [[24, 22], [33, 64], [13, 95]], 
                "Модель 2": [[26, 23], [34, 66], [15, 92]]},
        "Запчасть 3": {
                "Модель 1": [[23, 40], [51, 74], [33, 75]], 
                "Модель 2": [[21, 42], [53, 74], [34, 72]]}
        }
```

Я хочу через какую нибудь библиотеку обучить нейросеть понимать к какой запчасти относится какая модель.
Далее дать на вход массив вида `[[13, 10], [15, 10], [12, 16]]` и чтобы программа сказала мне с какой вероятностью этот массив совпадает с другими массивами.

В данном случает должен быть вывод "Входной массив совпадает с "Запчасть 3" с вероятность 95%"

Числа в массива соответствуют размерам объекта в см. Сам словарь больше 100 элементов, моделей для каждой запчасти так же больше 100 и будет расти. Сами элементы моделей совпадают по столбцам, условно первый столбец высота, второй ширина.

p.s. Естественно никой код не нужен, нужна помощь понимании какую технологию использовать, названия библиотек хотя бы для python. Может у TensorFlow чего есть, использую его сейчас для обнаружения объектов.

**Коэффициент корреляции между векторами и XOR не рассматриваю.**

Comment: И всё же вам сначала придётся определиться с метрикой. Т.е. выбрать функцию, которая будет характеризовать метод близости двух массивов. Потому что не зная природу этих чисел непонятно, как считать "расстояние" между ними.

Comment: @CrazyElf немного не понял, зачем знать природу чисел? Может я не совсем понятно написал, но в общем у меня есть 3D камера, я ей сканирую объекты и получаю координаты 100 точек этого объекта, точки всегда на одних местах. Сами числа равны расстоянию от камеры до объекта в см. Мне получается нужно сравнить свой массив с каждым массивом в датасете и вывести % совпадения моего массива с остальными

Comment: А почему числа идут двойками - это расстояние от двух разных камер?

Comment: Ну хорошо, вот допустим есть два массива, для простоты из одной пары чисел [10, 20] и [11, 20]. Какой "процент совпадения" нужно тут насчитать? 50% - потому что только одно из двух чисел совпало. Или 90% - одно число точно совпало, а другое на 1/10 разошлось, берём наибольшую разницу. Или ещё можно 100500 способов подсчёта совпадения придумать. Это и называется "метрика". Считать расстояние/совпадение между наборами чисел можно разными способами.

Comment: @CrazyElf постарался упростить задачу, там тройками идут, координаты X Y Z до каждой из 100 точек объекта
Ага, понял, да тут совпадение 90%. Ахах опять сейчас придём к тому что нейросеть не нужна, но я бы не хотел просто делить одно число на другое.

Так как там расстояния в см, идеально совпадать они никогда не будут. Возможно нужен параметр. Что если [10, _] +- на 5% отличается от [11, _] то считать это как одно и тоже число

Comment: Ну тогда это видимо евклидово расстояние. Или может "манхэттенское", ну не суть. Вам нужна любая библиотека, которая умеет считать расстояния, просто посчитать каждое с каждым. Например, `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` умеет. А если вдруг у вас точек миллионы и считать надо быстро, то есть специальные библиотеки чтобы и такое быстро  считать. Зачем тут нейросеть и правда непонятно.

Comment: Просто нейросети нужны там, где данных очень много, и зависимости неявные. А если данных немного и есть чёткое понимание, как таргет зависит от данных, то нейросети - это просто модная игрушка. Сделать с их помощью тоже можно, но непонятно, зачем - они будут использовать те же самые данные, что и более простые модели, только менее эффективно.

Comment: @CrazyElf а в чём разница будет при использовании scipy с euclidean или cityblock? Я так понимаю евклидовое будет меньше чем манхэттенское что упростит процесс сравнивания